# elemento Vue js no funciona

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js

La vista no reconoce el elemento `<Meta> </Meta>`, no muestra la tabla ni los elementos declarados en meta.vue

Esta es mi vista

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Lista</div>

                <div id="app">
                    <Meta></Meta>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

al correr el proyecto no muestra nada
(meta.vue es)

```
<template>
    <div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Lista de Metas</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Sub meta</th>
                        <th>Descripción</th>
                        <th>Año</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="meta in metas" :key="meta.key">
                        <td>{{ meta.META_intId }}</td>
                        <td>{{ meta.META_varSubmeta }}</td>
                        <td>{{ meta.META_varDescripcion }}</td>
                        <td>{{ meta.META_intYear }}</td>                       
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                metas: []
            };
        },
        created(){
            this.fetchMeta();
        },
        methods:{
            fetchMeta(){
                axios.get('/meta').then(respon=>{
                    this.metas=respon.data.data
                });
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

y el app.js es:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('meta',require('./components/meta.vue'));

const app=new Vue({
    el:'#app'
});
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo leas [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!.. Decis que no muestra nada.. ni un error en la consola? seguro ahi hay un error. y como lo estas corriendo?

Comment: y seguro que tu respuesta es respon.data.data?

Comment: @gbianchi si es, funciona bien; el problema era con <meta> cuando la cambie por <smeta> funciona normal

Comment: Recuerda que a vue no le importa si utilizas camelcase para la declaración de componentes, pero a los navegadores si. Según lo que recomienda la documentación es utilizar dos palabras en minúsculas separadas por un guion medio. Para que si en algún momento la W3C decide lanzar nuevas etiquetas no choquen con las etiquetas de tus componentes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema era con `<Meta></Meta>`, html no la reconocía así que tuve que cambiarla por `<Smeta></Smeta>`, cambie el nombre del componente `Vue.component('smeta',require('./components/meta.vue'));` en app.js, Meta es un palabra reservada en HTML.